# How to connect Kafka to speed sensor

Tags: python, apache-kafka, streaming

***New to Kafka***

I have a usecase to monitor the speed of the vehicles.
I need to collect the speeds using Kafka and store in a DB.

I want this to achieve using Kafka-Python.

How will I bridge between Kafka producer and the speed sensor. I Just need the path how can chose the correct one.

Comment: There is not enough information to answer your question, is there an API exposed by the speed sensor? In which protocol? There are example for python kafka producer across the internet, what have you tried already? 

Comment: I have not tried any producers yet. I will have a look.